# Sum where values of a column matches without number of rows changing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to values of a column where values of another column matches. Below is a sample of my data.

```
DT                      No_of_records    LD_VOY_N  LD_VSL_M
2017-05-06 04:00:00.000         7          0002W   pqo emzmnwp
2017-05-06 20:00:00.000         6          0002W   pqo emzmnwp
2017-05-02 04:00:00.000         1          0007E   omq ynzmeoyn
2017-05-01 08:00:00.000         2          0016W   rmhp sunhpnw
2017-05-01 12:00:00.000         1          0016W   rmhp sunhpnw
2017-05-05 12:00:00.000         2          0019N   omq wqmsy
2017-05-06 04:00:00.000         12         0019N   omq wqmsy
```

Below is my desired output

```
DT                      No_of_records    LD_VOY_N   LD_VSL_M      Total_no_of_records
2017-05-06 04:00:00.000         7          0002W    pqo emzmnwp   13
2017-05-06 20:00:00.000         6          0002W    pqo emzmnwp   13
2017-05-02 04:00:00.000         1          0007E    omq ynzmeoyn  1
2017-05-01 08:00:00.000         2          0016W    rmhp sunhpnw  3
2017-05-01 12:00:00.000         1          0016W    rmhp sunhpnw  3
2017-05-05 12:00:00.000         2          0019N    omq wqmsy     14
2017-05-06 04:00:00.000         12         0019N    omq wqmsy     14
```

I am trying to find the Total_no_of_records column. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a window function by `LD_VOY_N`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(No_of_records) over (partition by LD_VOY_N) as Total_no_of_records
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DT,No_of_records,LD_VOY_N,LD_VSL_M ,COUNT(DISTINCT (DT,No_of_records,LD_VOY_N,LD_VSL_M )) as Total_no_of_records from tablename
group by DT,No_of_records,LD_VOY_N,LD_VSL_M
```